# Batch script to move compress and delete files

Tags: winrar

I have a batch script that does the following

```
@ECHO OFF

REM move files older than 2 days from the incoming directory to the incoming archive directory
robocopy D:\Agentrics\integration\download D:\Agentrics\integration\download\archive /MOV /MINAGE:2

REM Zip files in the Archieve directory that are older than one week
FOR %%A IN (D:\Agentrics\integration\download\archive\*.txt*, D:\Agentrics\integration\download\archive\*.cpi*) DO "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -r -to7d D:\Agentrics\integration\download\archive\"%%~nA.zip" "%%A"

REM Delete Original files after they are zipped
forfiles /p D:\Agentrics\integration\download\archive /s /m *.txt* /d -7 /c "cmd /c del /q @path"
forfiles /p D:\Agentrics\integration\download\archive /s /m *.cpi* /d -7 /c "cmd /c del /q @path"

REM Delete files that are older than 6 months from the archive directory
forfiles /p D:\Agentrics\integration\download\archive /s /m *.zip* /d -180 /c "cmd /c del /q @path"
pause
```

Question 1:
When i run the script i get WinRAR diagnostic messages for some files. For example if there are files in the incoming directory that are not older than two days i get this message."WinRAR Diagnostic messages: No File To Add". Because of this message the scripts stops until i click on the close button of the dialogue box. I am using the free version of WinRAR and its not expired

Question 2: I have two seprate command in the script above. One is for zipping the files older than a week and the other one is deleting the original files after they are zipped. How can i link those two commands so that if some reason the files did not get zipped they should also not get deleted. Or is is there a command to break the script if the files did not get zipped? I just want to zipp the files first and then delete the original ones

Answer (score 0):

I sugest to use

```
@ECHO OFF

REM Move files older than 2 days from the incoming directory to the incoming archive directory.
robocopy D:\Agentrics\integration\download D:\Agentrics\integration\download\archive /MOV /MINAGE:2

REM Move each file in the archive directory that is older than one week into a ZIP archive.
FOR %%A IN (D:\Agentrics\integration\download\archive\*.txt*, D:\Agentrics\integration\download\archive\*.cpi*) DO "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" m -afzip -ep -inul -to7d -y "D:\Agentrics\integration\download\archive\%%~nA.zip" "%%A"

REM Delete files that are older than 6 months from the archive directory.
forfiles /p D:\Agentrics\integration\download\archive /s /m *.zip* /d -180 /c "cmd /c del /q @path"
```

The entire process can be simplified by using command `m` which means *move to archive* instead of command `a` which means *add to archive*. **WinRAR** removes the file only after successful compression.

Using switch `-afzip` informs **WinRAR** explicitly to use ZIP instead of RAR compression.

The switch `-ep` results in removing path from the file names inside the archive.

The output of any error or warning message can be suppressed with switch `-inul`. This switch is mainly for the console version `Rar.exe` (not supporting ZIP copmression) for output to stdout and stderr, but may work also for **WinRAR**. I have never seen a diagnostic message to confirm on my tests using `WinRAR.exe` version 4.20 when the ZIP file was not created because the file was not older than 7 days. I have seen the warning on using `Rar.exe` creating a RAR archive and not using `-inul`, but also with no need for a key hit even without using switch `-y`.

I removed switch `-r` for recursive archiving as not needed here with always moving only 1 file to a ZIP archive.

The unmodified switch `-to7d` results in archiving only files older than 7 days.

Last the switch `-y` is added to assume **Yes** on all queries although I have never seen one on my tests.

One more hint:
On NTFS partitions the attribute **compressed** can be set on a folder resulting in an automatic ZIP compression of all files copied or created in this folder to save disk storage.