# Batch - Create zip archive without keeping original path

Tags: batch-file, compression, winrar

I'm trying to create a zip archive by executing this command line :

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -afzip "C:\Users\toto\Desktop\file.zip" "C:\Users\toto\workspace\thing\trunk\chrome" "C:\Users\toto\workspace\thing\trunk\defaults"
```

The file.zip is created on the desktop as wanted but when I open the archive I find the whole path to access the chrome and defaults directories. It is "Users\toto\workspace\thing\trunk"
I'd like to have directly my chrome and defaults directories as first nodes in the archive.
Is is possible ?

Answer (score 3):

Add `-ep1` switch to your command

Answer (score 0):

Just `cd` there first:

```
cd \Users\toto\workspace\thing\trunk
```

then make it

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -afzip "C:\Users\toto\Desktop\file.zip" chrome defaults
```

Answer (score 0):

It is interesting to read this question as about 50% of all answers given on questions tagged with the WinRAR tag contain either switch `-ep` or `-ep1`.

For example:

- [Batch script to zip all the files without the parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696606/batch-script-to-zip-all-the-files-without-the-parent-folder)
- [Batch script to move compress and delete files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257650/batch-script-to-move-compress-and-delete-files)
- [Simply compress 1 folder in batch with WinRAR command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24397921/simply-compress-1-folder-in-batch-with-winrar-command-line)
- [How to create self-extracting RAR archive not showing anything on execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698055/how-to-create-self-extracting-rar-archive-not-showing-anything-on-execution)
- [Compress several subfolders with batch file (win7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22986966/compress-several-subfolders-with-batch-file-win7)

It looks like many **WinRAR** users prefer asking over searching or looking in help of **WinRAR** or reading command line documentation **Rar.txt** in program files directory of **WinRAR**.

It might be helpful to answer this frequently asked **WinRAR** related question already in winrar tag wiki.